# FFmpeg skip audio files

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to convert videos in a batch file but sometimes there is pure audio files in the mix and they get converted to. This causes some headaches because the audio is transcoded and the file size ends up bigger.

Is there any way to easily detect this and prevent transcoding(I need to rename files though to work with how I transcode).

I guess ideally there would be a utility I can call that returns 0 or 1 exitcode if the file is only audio or not.

Comment: Which OS/shell?

Comment: @Gyan windows...

Comment: See [Using ffprobe to check audio-only files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278277/using-ffprobe-to-check-audio-only-files/32289198#32289198) (specifically see "Output nothing if there is no audio" example).

Comment: @llogan That was what I was thinking but I have no idea how to use it in a batch that will work with errorlevel. All the info seems to simply print out rather than create a proper errorlevel code.

Comment: @JoeBelow This is essentially two questions in one. 1) How to find out if file has audio. 2) How to script it in a batch file. Questions like this don't always get answered because the answerer has to know both topics. I know nothing of batch, so I suggest adding the appropriate tag for that aspect of the question. Instead of focusing on errorlevel you can check to see if the `ffprobe` output is null (which means no audio) and use if statements (at least that's how I may do it in bash).

Comment: @llogan I guess then I have to answer it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The follow code dumps the codec types to a text file. If the file contains both audio and video then it can be converted. It may not be an optimal solution but so far has worked well.

```
ffprobe.exe -v quiet -show_entries stream=codec_type -of csv=p=0 "%%a" > tmpff.tmp
findstr ^audio tmpff.tmp >nul 2>&1
if !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (
    findstr ^video tmpff.tmp >nul 2>&1
    if !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (
        echo Transcoding %%a            

    )
)
```